# PHP rand() function

Tags: php, random

I want to make something like a anti spam system, I've got this HTML:

```
What is <?php echo $six; ?> + <?php echo $rand1; ?> <input type="text" name="human" id="human">
```

And for these variables:

```
$human = @$_POST['human'];
$rand1 = rand(1, 9);
$six = 6; 
$res = $rand1 + $six;
```

Then I do:

```
if($human==$res){
  echo "Correct";
}else{
  echo "Incorrect";
}
```

This is not working! Any ideas?

Comment: Is that html code part of the same php file where you are calling the `rand(1,9)`?

Comment: You have to store somewhere correct value.

Comment: @vinodadhikary Yes it is

Comment: Input tags need a `/` at the end before the bracket is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to provide your $res or $rand1 variable value via your html form - changing your php to something like this:

```
$human = @$_POST['human'];
$res = @$_POST['res'];

if($human==$res){
  echo "Correct";
}else{
  echo "Incorrect";
}

$rand1 = rand(1, 9);
$six = 6; 
$res = $rand1 + $six;
```

Then adding:

```
<input type="hidden" name="res" value="<php echo $res;?>">
```

into your html form

Comment: Should be `<input type="hidden" name="res" value="<php echo $res;?>" />`

Comment: I wonder what the point of this file would be if you are echoing value of `$res` in that input field.  Who is supposed to do the calculation and put the value in the text field?

Comment: I'm assuming Gs is trying to deter bots - by providing a basic dynamic maths puzzle to solve. Hoping that only a human user would be likely to complete it.

Comment: Do you guys know any different way to do a anti spam system?

Comment: you could use google's reCAPTCHA. Their simple step by step guide is available her: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php - good luck.